# I want to dispose passwordcontroller

Tags: flutter

Once I clicked onto the log out button it return to the login screen which is good but I don't want to display email id and password again. 
Please check the code from the given link below:- 
https://flutter-examples.com/flutter-online-user-login-using-php-mysql-api/

Can anybody please write the code in the comment for me and tell me where should I paste this code. Actually I am learning flutter and I don't have much exposure to init method or dispose method. [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add dispose method inside LoginUserState class to add method below declare a controller

```
// Getting value from TextField widget.
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();
```

Add this

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the
    // widget tree.
    emailController.clear();
    passwordController.clear();
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Comment: @HarshRaj: Add two clear method in dispose method, Please add that and check

Answer (score 0):

For you to achieve this, add the code snippet below to your `LoginUser` class:

```
class LoginUser extends StatefulWidget {

LoginUserState createState() => LoginUserState();

}

class LoginUserState extends State {


  // Getting value from TextField widget.
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();


// add this code snippet to your LoginUser screen
@override
  void dispose() {
    // dispose the controllers so they don't display values on the login screen after logging out
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```